# Footer stacking in IE7 only

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I've been working on a re-skin of a website for a client at work, and it's all going splendidly, however I keep having the footer stack vertically when I view the page in Internet Explorer 7.

It looks fine across all other platforms, but once viewed in IE7 it stacks.

Can someone take a look at the code and see what if there is something I maybe missed?
this is the footer HTML. I'm trying to attach the CSS, but it says it's too many characters?

```html
<% 
Dim WebSession
If isObject(Session("WebSession")) Then
 Set WebSession = Session("WebSession")
End if
%>
<!--#include VIRTUAL="/4YSIncludes/adovbs.inc"-->
<!--#include VIRTUAL="/4YSIncludes/Constant4YS.h"-->
<!--#include file="../../Includes/Constants.h"-->
<!--#include file="../../Includes/Functions.asp"-->
<!--#include VIRTUAL="/4YSIncludes/CPCommonFunctions.asp"-->
<!--#include file="../../Includes/WebTags.asp"-->


<div id="footer">
    <ul id="social">
      <li><a href="https://twitter.com/carrabbas" target="_blank"><img src="/CP001/Sitegraphics/6164/twitter.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Carrabbas" target="_blank"><img src="/CP001/Sitegraphics/6164/facebook.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/MisterCarrabba" target="_blank"><img src="/CP001/Sitegraphics/6164/youtube.png"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="footer_links">
       <li><a href="http://www.carrabbas.com/Content/press-room-fact-sheet">Press</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.carrabbas.com/content/diversity-carrabbas-diversity">Diversity</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.carrabbas.com/content/career-opportunities">Careers</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.carrabbas.com/Store/Catering">Catering</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.tellcarrabbas.com/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1">Survey</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.carrabbas.com/Content/privacy-policy">Legal</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.carrabbas.com/Contact/ContactUs">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="footer_copy">
      <li><span class="copyright">&#0169; &nbsp;2014 Bloomin'Brands, Inc</span></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <div id="cardways_footer"> <%=WTGetFooterBottomText%>&nbsp; | <a href="<%=WTGetPrivacyPolicyLink%>">Gift Card Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="<%=WTGetTOCLink%>">Gift Card Terms of Service</a> | <a href="<%=WTGetHelpLink%>">FAQs</a> <a href="http://www.arroweye.com"> <img class="logo2" width="124" height="29" border="0" align="absmiddle" 
    src="<% =WebPath & Channel & "/SiteGraphics/6164/poweredByArroweye.gif" %>" /></a></div>
  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just Aside ... really IE7 ?? Less than 0.7%

Comment: You'll need to include the relevant CSS for anyone to be able to assist with this issue, try to reduce it to only that which replicates the problem if you are hitting a character limit. You should also remove the classic ASP from your example.

Comment: unfortunately yes, IE7.
the client requested this re-skin work for IE7-current because apparently people still are in the stone age.

Comment: @danko While that is my first thought whenever I see older versions of IE specified in questions, there can be legitimate reasons why it needs to work in old versions.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes Hopefully those legitimate reasons will end soon, and everything will be at least IE9+ with XP now being un-supported

Comment: You may be using display:inline-block which is supported in ie8 and up but not ie7. For ie7 right after display:inline-block, put *display:inline (don't forget the asterisk). Also look up browser specific hacks. IE7 also doesn't support box-sizing:border-box which may also be the culprit, in that case, use the hacks to change the width on IE7 of various items to content-box sizing.

Comment: Don't get me wrong Danko and Nunners I agree with you, but some times your hands are tied. @Edrroweye Are you using `display: inline-block;` on the `li`?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you have a stray `</section>`in there.

Comment: Got the problem fixed with a little bit of footer code tweaking!